# Javascript get event id

Tags: javascript, closures

I am using Javascript and am creating my function within a closure, the problem I'm having is getting the id of the button the user has pressed.

The following code works when not in the closure, but when I place it inside it doesn't seem to work.

Please help, thanks in advance for any help.

code to get id...

```
var id = event.target.id;
```

within closure...

```
var closure = (function(){

    var id;

    return{
         getId: function(){

             id = event.target.id;

         }
    };
}());
```

Comment: The "event" variable is only a global in Internet Explorer.

Comment: you don't seem to have a reference to document anywhere in the closure so that might be why? Dunno though, just a though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're merely assigning `id` to some value, but `id` is not accessible due to the closure.

You should instead `return` the value so that you can get the result and actually use it:

```
getId: function() {
    return event.target.id;
}
```

You also don't need `var id;` since there is no reason for a local variable - you seem to just want to get the current ID. The `id` variable is nowhere accessible and you're also not accessing it inside the closure, so it doesn't serve any purpose here.